# Hyper V checkpoints with an Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, restore, azure

Is there any thing in Azure VMs similar to Hyper V checkpoints? I want to preserve the state of an Azure vm, deploy software builds for test and debugging and quickly revert. I do not want or need a scheduled backup. Nor do I want to deploy that checkpoint to a new vm (which is what snapshots seem to be for). Ideally this would be done via the web portal in a click or two like the Hyper VM interface. Searched quite a bit of azure documentation but this functionality seems to be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I stumbled on the equivalent functionality. Create a snapshot. Create a disk from the snapshot and use the 'Swap OS disk' functionality to revert